# How can I get item property from an array with node-config

Tags: node-config

I can not get item from an array in the configuration file.

```
{ 
 "crawlerConfigurations":{
        "ClickDelay": 100,
        "TypeDelay": 200,
        "Selectors": {
            "Search": [
                {
                    "SearchInitUrl": "https://www.wukong.com"
                 }
          ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the `SearchInitUrl` prop of  first Search item, and I'm using

```
config.get(`crawlerConfigurations.Selectors.Search[0].SearchInitUrl`)
config.get(`crawlerConfigurations.Selectors.Search.[0].SearchInitUrl`)
```

did not work

Hope someone would help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend arrays in configs because they're treated as a whole from an override perspective (like strings are arrays of characters, and you can't override a substring).

That said, sometimes you want that behavior. When you do, the following should work

```
config.get('crawlerConfigurations.Selectors.Search.0.SearchInitUrl');
```

The number zero (0) is a variable name like the other names in the path. Not sure why the original question had a ':' in the string, but that was a bug.

Comment: (Loren West is the author of node-config).

Comment: It would be good document array support on [Common Usage](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Common-Usage) page of the wiki.

Comment: Thanks so much. I used node-config like dot net configuration, my bad.Thanks